# Fail to display the custom cell file in my TableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cell, nib

Iv made a NIB custom cell file but I fail to display the custom cell file in my tableView at all. The code is error free and runs but I'm struggling to display the Custom Cell. I Initially thought my problem was from the Unwind Segue that I created to pass the data from the InputScreen to the ViewController but I'm just not sure what the issue could be at this point?

Any help what's so ever would be much appreciated.

MAIN VIEWCONTROLLER

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    var IzParcelz = [IzParcel]()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "IzparcelCell", bundle: nil)
        tableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "IzparcelCell")
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }
    // MARK: - TableView data source
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return IzParcelz.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "IzparcelCell", for: indexPath) as! IzparcelCell
   
        let izPackage = IzParcelz[indexPath.row]
        cell.nameLabel.text = izPackage.name
        cell.addressLabel.text = izPackage.address
        cell.trackingNumLabel.text = izPackage.trackingNumber

        return cell
    }
    // MARK: - TableView Delegate
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            IzParcelz.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
            IzParcel.saveIzParcel(IzParcelz)
            
        }
    }

    @IBAction func prepareForUnwind(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {

        guard segue.identifier == "saveUnwind" else { return }
        
        let sourceViewController = segue.source as! InputViewController
        
        if let P = sourceViewController.izParcel {
            if let selectedIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                IzParcelz[selectedIndexPath.row] = P
                tableView.reloadRows(at: [selectedIndexPath], with: .none)
            } else {
                let newIndexPath = IndexPath(row: IzParcelz.count, section: 0)
                IzParcelz.append(P)
                tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath], with: .automatic)
            }
        }
        
        IzParcel.saveIzParcel(IzParcelz)
    }
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showDetails" {
            let izViewController = segue.destination as! InputViewController
            let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
            let selectedTodo = IzParcelz[indexPath.row]

            izViewController.izParcel = selectedTodo
        }
    }
}
```

INPUT VIEWCONTROLLER

```
import UIKit

class InputViewController: UITableViewController {
    
    var izParcel: IzParcel?
    
    @IBOutlet weak var statusTextLabel: UITextField!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var nameTextLabel: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var addressTextLabel: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var trackingNumTextLabel: UITextField!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var notesTextLabel: UITextField!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var statusUpdateTextLabel: UIDatePicker!
    @IBOutlet weak var dateAndTimeTextLabel: UIDatePicker!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var saveButton: UIButton!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        if let izParcels = izParcel {
            nameTextLabel.text = izParcels.name
            addressTextLabel.text = izParcels.address
            trackingNumTextLabel.text = izParcels.trackingNumber
            notesTextLabel.text = izParcels.notes
            dateAndTimeTextLabel.date = izParcels.dateAndTime
            statusUpdateTextLabel.date = izParcels.statusUpdated
        }
    }
    
    @IBAction func deleteButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    @IBAction func saveButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print("PressedButtttonnnnTesst")
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "saveUnwind", sender: self)
}
        func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
            guard segue.identifier == "saveUnwind" else { return }
            
            let name = nameTextLabel.text!
            let address = addressTextLabel.text!
            let trackingNumber = trackingNumTextLabel.text!
            let notes = notesTextLabel.text!
            let dates = dateAndTimeTextLabel.date
            let statusUpdate = statusUpdateTextLabel.datePickerMode
            
            izParcel = IzParcel(name: name, address: address, trackingNumber: trackingNumber, notes: notes, dateAndTime: dates, statusUpdated: dates)
        }
    }
```

IZPARCEL CELL

```
import UIKit

class IzparcelCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var addressLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var trackingNumLabel: UILabel!
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }   
}
```

[[image: Screenshot of Unwind Segue Connection]]
[image: Screenshot of what's supposed to display in the TableView]

Comment: You have the prepare(segue..) declared inside saveButton() function : it will never be called.

Comment: *"fail to display the custom cell file in my tableView"* -- do you mean it *never* displays? Or do you mean you see the cells at first, but they don't display when you *return* from another controller?

Comment: @DonMag The custom cell never displays at all

Comment: @izzziz - in the code you've shown, you declare `var IzParcelz = [IzParcel]()` - which is an **empty** array... but you never add any data to that array. So, you have no cells to show.

Comment: @DonMag The problem occurs when I go through the InputScreen and I try to add the information to the array to get displayed on to the mainViewController using the Custom Cell

Comment: @izzziz - ok.. is your `prepareForUnwind` executing? If so, set a breakpoint and step through it, inspecting the objects. Is the data valid?

Comment: @DonMag thank you, I got it from here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228912/discussion-between-izzziz-and-donmag).

Answer (score 0):

All the code I had was correct except for the order of the code. After reviewing and reallocating the prepare for segue declaration that was inside the saveButton Action to just outside it. I was able to pass the data from the InputScreen to the Custom TableView Cell in the TableView on the mainScreen.